# Flutter flutter_inappwebview "onEnterFullscreen"

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter flutter_inappwebview rotate to landscape when the user click the fullscreen video. In the documentation flutter_inappwebview  says.

- onEnterFullscreen: Event fired when the current page has entered full
  screen mode.
- onExitFullscreen: Event fired when the current page has    exited
  full screen mode.

  ```
     Container(
         height: globals.screenHeight * 0.25,
         color: Colors.white,
         child: Column(children: <Widget>[
           Expanded(
             child: Container(
               margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
               child: InAppWebView(
                 initialUrl:
                     "http://URL/play.html?name=123456789",
                 initialHeaders: {},
                 onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                   webView = controller;
                 },
                 onEnterFullscreen: AutoOrientation.landscapeAutoMode(),
                 onLoadStart:
                     (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
                   setState(() {
                     this.url = url;
                   });
                 },
                 onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller,
                     String url) async {
                   setState(() {
                     this.url = url;
                   });
                 },
                 onProgressChanged:
                     (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
                   setState(() {
                     this.progress = progress / 100;
                   });
                 },
               ),
             ),
           ),
         ]
       )
     ),
  ```

when the page load, the phone automatic landscape, and i received this error.

[image]

what i want is, when the user click the fullscreen, the video automatic landscape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `onEnterFullscreen` is waiting for a `(InAppViewController) => void` but you are assigning the result of `AutoOrientation.landscapeAutoMode()`.

```dart
onEnterFullscreen: AutoOrientation.landscapeAutoMode(),
```

So, that function is evaluated each time that `build` method is called. That is the reason why you have those two weird behaviors:

- **Landscape automatically on load**
- **Exception because types don't match**

To solve that, you need to assign the callback in this way:

```dart
onEnterFullscreen: (controller) { AutoOrientation.landscapeAutoMode() },
```